# Galois theory about automorphisms of the field of rational functions

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Suppose That $F$ is a field and $G=Aut(F(x))$ is the group of field automorphisms of the field of [rational functions](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Rational_function#Definitions) $F(x)$ and fix $F$, and that $E\subset F(x)$ is the fixed field of G.
please prove

1. if $F$ is infinite then $E=F$
2. if $F$ is finite then $E\neq F$

This is a homework problem about Galois theory but I do not know how to use Galois theory to solve it.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be true - if $F$ has any automorphism, like $F=\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)$ - then there is an automorphism which does not fix $F$. Do you want $G$ to be the set of automorphisms of $F(x)$ that fix $F$?

Comment: I am not sure you need to use *Galois theory* specifically. It might well be an excercise to get you used to the notions.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yes I correct it.

Comment: Assuming $G$ is the automorphisms of $F(x)$ which fix $F$ try to show that any such automorphism will be determined by its action on $x$ and figure out the constraint due to degree considerations...